# npm install always stuck at that extract:time-grunt

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, keystonejs

I'm learning Keystone and trying to practice it on real Digital Ocean droplet. Everything go fine, until I stuck at `npm install`.

```
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer requires a build toolchain, use it instead!
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
Killed        .....] - extract:time-grunt: sill doParallel extract 1194
```

What every I do, reinstall everything from clean state, the `npm install` always stucks at that `extract:time-grunt`

When I check the `node_modules` folder, there is nothing there.

I've tried to search Google and also here, but can not find any good answer. I can run good on my Mac localhost, everything just fine.

Server: Ubuntu 16.04, Node 4.5.0, npm 3.10.16

It is just a simple and really basic Keystone project, I did not do anything advanced.

Comment: Please do not add remarks about "sneaky hide below your keyboard" - downvoting or flagging are merely systems to keep questions focussed and on-topic. The question itself however seems fine to me - just remember that not everything is on-topic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think, you are **running out of memory**. try to [add some swap memory](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) before you start npm install.

Comment: Thank you, I will try and feed back soon.

Comment: Yeah, added swap file and problem solved. Thank you so much.